# Image Gets rotated captured from camera

Tags: android, camera, exif, image-rotation

In my app the user captures an image from the camera or selects from the gallery it converts it to pdf and Uploads it to the server, Now my problem is that the images captured from the camera are rotated on some devices, I do have code to try to solve this but it does not work

```
 private void PDFCreation(){
        PdfDocument document=new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo;
        PdfDocument.Page page;
        Canvas canvas;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < list.size(); i++)  {
            pageInfo=new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(992, 1432, 1).create();
            page=document.startPage(pageInfo);
            canvas=page.getCanvas();
            image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(i));
            image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 980, 1420, true);
            image.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300);
            canvas.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300);
            canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
            float rotation=0;
            try {
                ExifInterface exifInterface=new ExifInterface(selectedPhoto);
                int orientation=exifInterface.getAttributeInt(TAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: {
                        rotation=-90f;
                        break;
                    }
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: {
                        rotation=-180f;
                        break;
                    }
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270: {
                        rotation=90f;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            canvas.rotate(rotation);
            document.finishPage(page);
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") String directory_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mypdf/";
        File file=new File(directory_path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp=(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")).format(new Date());
        String targetPdf=directory_path + timeStamp + ".pdf";
         filePath=new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("main", "error " + e.toString());
            Toasty.error(this, "Error making PDF" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        document.close();
```

Any Advice or where is the problem, there is no error codes or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rotate your canvas after drawBitmap. You have to first rotate it and then use drawBitmap i.e

```
        float rotation=0;
        try {
            ExifInterface exifInterface=new ExifInterface(selectedPhoto);
            int orientation=exifInterface.getAttributeInt(TAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: {
                    rotation=-90f;
                    break;
                }
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: {
                    rotation=-180f;
                    break;
                }
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270: {
                    rotation=90f;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(rotation);

        //canvas is rotated now use drawBitmap
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question will this rotate the bitmap aswell?, I assume it does not seeing that the canvas is rotated and then the bitmap gets painted

Comment: No. Canvas.rotate tranform matrix and canvas.drawBitmap draw bitmap transformed by this matrix and your image rotated correctly.  I will suggest you use Matrix because it is more efficient like

Comment: Something like this??   `Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0,
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
            canvas.rotate(rotation);
            canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
            document.finishPage(page);`

Comment: Yes but then you don't have to use canvas Bitmap.createBitmap will give you required bitmap. If you find this answer helpful please give an upvote.

Comment: The canvas is required for the PDF